# End event in twit library

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I've been using twit library to query Twitter. When I try to obtain some user timeline, I use something like this:

```
var Twit=require('twit');

var gtl=function getTimeline(userName){

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:yourKey
    consumer_secret:yourSecret
    access_token:yourToken
    access_token_secret:yourTokenSecret
});

var est=[];

T.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name:userName,count:100}, function(err, reply) {
    est=reply;
});

console.log(est);
```

'get' method seems to be acting asynchronously, so 'est' will be empty till request finishes. Nevertheless, I don't find an 'end' event in order to fire any action only AFTER response is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@franaf,

Probably I am late here.

The callback will only get fired and will automatically act as the end. The twit module is smart enough to handle chunks and will make this callback only after the complete response is received.